# Least Squares Algorithm with Inverse Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matlab, least-squares

Given an overdetermined linear system $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ with $A < 0$ and $b < 0$. What is a good way to numerically determine
$$ \min_x \left\lVert \frac{1}{A x} - \frac{1}{b}\right\rVert_2^2,$$
where the fractions $\frac{1}{A x}$ and $\frac{1}{b}$ are element wise. Especially, what is the best way to approach this in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's [fminsearch](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) would appear to be well-suited for this problem.

> xMin=fminsearch(@(x) norm(1./(A*x)-1./b)^2 , ones(m,1));

It might be necessary to put in some constraints to avoid hitting $x=0$.

Alternatively, there is [fminunc](http://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/minimization-with-gradient-and-hessian.html) which is gradient-based and can make use of the objective function, its gradient and its [hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), but you have to manually calculate those (matlab, alas, does not do [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Automatic_differentiation_using_dual_numbers)).
$$\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=\sum_i\left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right)^2$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=2\sum_i \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=2\sum_i \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left(\frac{1}{\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=2\sum_i \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \left(\frac{-A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}\right)$$
this is the gradient.

For the Hessian we must derive again
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}2\sum_i \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \left(\frac{-A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=2\sum_i \left(\left(\frac{A_{i,l}A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}\right)  + \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_l}\left(\frac{-A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_k\partial x_l}\left\|\frac{1}{A x}-\frac{1}{b}\right\|_2^2=2\sum_i \left(\left(\frac{A_{i,l}A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}\right)  + \left(\frac{1}{(A x)_i}-\frac{1}{b_i}\right) \left(\frac{2 A_{i,k}A_{i,l}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^3}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I have tried this option and it works, but isn't there any possibility to use a derivative based and more robust method?

Comment: I believe that there is a typo: $\frac{A_{i,l}A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^2}$ in the Hessian should be instead $\frac{A_{i,l}A_{i,k}}{(\sum_j A_{i,j}x_j)^4}$. Can you confirm this?